# RemoteSpringApplication leads to 403

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, hot-reload

I could reload application on edit with [RemoteSpringApplication](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-devtools.html) until I added spring security to my app,

with

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebAuthConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter { ..
```

etc

event though I added:

```
// TODO: this disable all security checks     httpSecurity.httpBasic().disable().authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll();
```

so all my rest calls still works without any auth,

as soon as I change the code and running RemoteSpringApplication detects the change it fails with:

```
Exception in thread "File Watcher" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unexpected 403 response uploading class files
```

How to prevent it?

Thx

Answer (score 1):

Add:

```
      .authorizeRequests()
      .antMatchers("/.~~spring-boot!~/**")
      .permitAll()
      .and()
```

to your Spring Security config near the top of your `http` method chain in the `configure(HttpSecurity http)` method and it'll disable Spring Security on the Spring Boot DevTools URL.

If you want to change this URL you can override it by changing the `spring.devtools.remote.context-path` property in your `application.properties`.

Make sure you're not running devtools in production of course!!